# Include JDatabaseDriver Joomla

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I am trying to connect to an external DB via Joomla using this code:

```
        $option = array(); //prevent problems
        $option['driver']   = 'mysql';            // Database driver name
        $option['host']     = 'host';    // Database host name
        $option['user']     = 'user';       // User for database authentication
        $option['password'] = 'password';   // Password for database authentication
        $option['database'] = 'database';      // Database name

        $external_db = JDatabaseDriver::getInstance($option);
```

I get the error Akeeba\Subscriptions\Site\Model\JDatabaseDriver' not found..
How can i fix it please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `Akeeba\Subscriptions\Site\Model\JDatabaseDriver` doesn't exist. Joomla has its own autoloader, so include [loader.php](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/master/libraries/loader.php) if you haven't already do and setup the autoloader with

```
\JLoader::setup();
\JLoader::import('joomla.factory');
```

The call `JDatabaseDriver` with

```
$external_db = \JDatabaseDriver::getInstance($option);
```

as `JDatabaseDriver` is in the global namespace.

Comment: Fatal error: Class 'Akeeba\Subscriptions\Site\Model\JLoader' not found in /usr/www/users/makerf/login/components/com_akeebasubs/Model/Subscribe.php

Comment: always a namespace problem, `JLoader` is in the global space, so use the global space. `\JLoader`

Comment: obviously it also applies to `JDatabaseDriver`, that's also in the global namespace

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot redeclare jexit() (previously declared in ......libraries/loader.php on line 624

Comment: what i have to write in my code? can you be more specific cause i dont know so much.. :/

Comment: i dont see to be loaded anywhere in my code..i try to connect also via PDO instead of JDatabaseDriver and i get the same error Class 'Akeeba\Subscriptions\Site\Model\PDO' not found...